# Is it possible to run bash builtin from non bash script?

Tags: macos, bash

Is it possible to run for example `history -w` for underlying bash shell from ruby script?
Or better is it possible to run builtin command for bash shell knowing only its pid?

The only way I found is to trap signal like `trap "history -w" SIGUSR1` and then send signal to process, but I am not sure that it is a good practice and USR1 is not used by bash, also this way I can execute max 2 commands (USR1 and USR2). And I have to define trap before using it.

I am on Mac so there is not SIGRTMIN..SIGRTMAX.

#### Why I need this:

I created ruby shell script `dt` which opens new tab next to current with same working dir, then I wrote [newTabHere.app](https://github.com/toy/newTabHere.app) that can do same thing but can do this even if tab is busy running something (I call it using [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/spark.php)). But it will be much better if history will be also same in duplicated tab and for `dt` I can just use `alias dt='history -w; dt'`, but how can I do this from `newTabHere.app`?

Comment: @Daniel: I clarified why I need this

Answer (score 1):

There's no off-the-shelf way to cause a shell to execute a command, other than typing in on its standard input. The easiest thing would be to have bash check some file, or run `history -w`, as part of `PROMPT_COMMAND` (a command that is executed before each prompt).

I think what you're after is in fact [Real-time history export amongst Bash terminal windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103944/real-time-history-export-amongst-bash-terminal-windows), and perhaps [Better bash history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/better-bash-history).

You might also consider using [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) (available in most Linux/OSX/other unix package repositories) and its `inc_append_history` and `share_history` [options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_16.html#SEC89).

Comment: `zsh` is maybe good, but it can't handle utf-8 input and this stops me right away (though I know it can print those chars)

Comment: @tig: UTF-8 is supported in zsh 4.3 (which in spite of being labeled “development” is definitely “reasonably stable”: it doesn't crash or anything, and new minor releases aren't even in the habit of having incompatible changes).

Answer (score 0):

For this specific use case I would recommend just adding `history -w` to your `PROMPT_COMMAND` (or in shell function that gets invoked thence).

More generally I would suggest having a queue for commands requested outside, and using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to run them:

```bsh
run_prompt_queue() {
  local f
  for f in ~/.bash_queue.d/$$-*
  do
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue # still works without nullglob
    . "$f"
    rm -fv "$f"
  done
}
PROMPT_COMMAND+=$'\n run_prompt_queue'
rm -v "$HOME/.bash_queue.d/$$-"* # clear random leftovers when PID is recycled
```

Then in your Python script, create a file containing the commands you want run, and then rename it to `sprintf("%s/.bash_queue.d/%u,%s", sys.env("HOME"), pid_of_bash, your_unique_suffix)`.

`pid_of_bash` is probably `sys.getppid()` or `sys.getsid()` but that can vary depending on the nesting level of the your scripts.

Obviously you can choose your own convention for naming the files, but I strongly suggest that you include the PID of the target shell, at least as an option.

If you don't care which particular shell
You could also trigger based on the pgrp, sid, tty, time-of-day, etc.)

Important tip: **make sure nobody else can write to your queue directory.**